# Re-checking with another airline at Incheon

Tags: check-in, vacations, icn

I am taking a flight from Bangkok to Incheon with a connection time of 2 hours. I have 2 bags. I need to go through immigration, pick up my bags and re-check again with Delta Airlines.  Do I have enough time to do this?

Comment: This is not enough time. Are you sure you need to recheck your bags?

Comment: I have 2 separate tickets n Airlines do not check bags thru unless in a single ticket x Anyways appreciate your response x now I know x merci

Answer (score 6):

> Do I have enough time to do this?

Impossible to predict with any certainty but it's likely you will miss your connection.

Delta closes the check in for international flights 1 hour before departure https://www.delta.com/us/en/check-in-security/check-in-time-requirements/international-check-in

Incheon Arrival procedures are here: https://www.airport.kr/ap_cnt/en/arr/entmap/t1/ent_t1.do

So you have only one hour to

- get off the plane
- Clear immigration
- Collect your baggage from the carousel
- Clear customs
- Go to the Delta check in counter and bag drop.

Baggage time and immigration/customs time vary a lot and are notoriously difficult to predict with any certainty. It certainly helps if you have status with the airline, fly business, or have some other means of getting priority treatment.

If all things work really well, than you have a chance of making it, but the odds are 50/50 at best.

Please note that if you miss your connection, you are entirely on your own and may have to buy a completely new ticket on the spot. As far as Delta is concerned you are a "no show" by your own fault.

I strongly recommend against this. Rebook, if any possible

Comment: And if the second flight is not the last on a ticket, then all subsequent flights on that ticket may be cancelled as well. If you are self-connecting, either take a flexible fare, or have as much time as possible between the flights, especially if the second flight is expensive.